# How do you view the JavaScript embedded in a PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a PDF, which I think has JavaScript embedded in it. Is it possible to see what that JavaScript is? And if so, how would I see it?

It's probably possible to hack something together with iText, but I would prefer something faster.

Comment: Try this http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: It's probably ActionScript and not JavaScript

Comment: @AlexW Is it true that PDF can embed ActionScript? When and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download iText RUPS: https://github.com/itext/rups/releases

Open the PDF using RUPS and you'll be able to look at all the PDF objects. iText RUPS isn't a PDF viewer, it's a PDF syntax browser.

Comment: Appears this is no longer available as a free download

Comment: @Carnix Please read what it says: iText RUPS has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/itext/rups You can download it here: https://github.com/itext/rups/releases See also https://itextpdf.com/itext5/rups

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer a fast method, just open the PDF with a text editor, e.g. NotePad++, and search on JavaScript.

In my case, I ran into a pdf that insisted on being printed instead of viewed. With NP++ I found this script:

```
<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.print\({bUI: true,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true}\);this.closeDoc\(\);)>>
```

The notation is a little weird, but obviously it has a Print command, followed by a Close command.

You can even replace the Close command with spaces, which is easy in Overwrite mode (press the Insert key to toggle to and from Overwrite mode). You need to keep the total nr of characters the same, to preserve the offset pointers in the PDF.
Then, the document can be viewed after cancelling the print command.

As it was a digitally signed document, of course the signature showed "invalid" :-)

Comment: If the pdf uses object streams, the Javascript may be compressed and, therefore, unrecognizable without decompression.

Comment: @mkl Correct. May even be encrypted. My point is that OP asked for a fast method and about JavaScript. My method is the fastest method. Only in case the doc turns out to be compressed/encrypted, or otherwise too complex, you should switch to another better and more specialized but slower method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this can be done directly in **Adobe Acrobat**:

1. First, more general and fast way *if you only need to know **whether there is any JavaScript code at all** inside the PDF*: it is enough to run `Remove Hidden Information` tool (`Tools → Protect` under `Protect & Standardize` section).

   After the tool finishes examining the document, you will see an entry called "Links, actions and javascripts" if the document contains any scripts or actions at all (note that these might be harmless actions like opening a website after clicking on a link).
2. Second, more precise and slightly slower way *if you need to see precisely **what scripts or actions are present** in the document*: open `Prepare Form` tool (`Tools → Prepare Form` under `Forms & Signatures` section) and click "Start". This will analyze the whole document.

   There, click on `More` in the middle of the right panel and choose either `All JavaScripts`, `Document JavaScripts` or `Document Actions` to see relevant information.

   *(Thanks goes to the [original source of the answer](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-to-detect-javascript-in-a-pdf/td-p/13605843) on the Adobe Community Forums.)*

Also note, however, that ***Adobe Acrobat is not a security tool for examining malicious JavaScript code***. If you positively *know* that there is some malicious code inside the PDF and you *know* that the attacker would try to obfuscate it, use a tool that is specifically created for this goal. For more info on this topic, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232213/1148501).