# Export JavaScript from PDF to external editor

Tags: javascript, pdf

How do I export the JavaScript source code of a pdf into an editor lets say atom or such? I have not been able to find the instructions of this online (only converting html to pdf and vice versa) I am just trying to export the JavaScript source code so that it is more easily readable. Has anyone ever done this before?

Comment: Reason for downvote please

Comment: Am i being dumb and overlooking something?

Comment: It seems like you're going about this the wrong way. Are you sure you can't find the source of the pdf instead of trying to **parse** it, which is what you're asking; how-to parse a pdf.

Comment: When I click all javascript it tells me to use an external editor but I cannot figure out how ...

Comment: Ughhh all these downvotes. In Adobe DC if I click tools then JS when I select All Javascript it does not open anything and tells me to use an external editor

Comment: I found the same question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342542/how-can-i-extract-a-javascript-from-a-pdf-file-with-a-command-line-tool

Comment: Your question is off-topic and should be moved to superuser or should be asked on an Adobe forum: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this question does not belong on StackOverflow, however, for the sake of helping out my fellow man:

If you want to export all of the JavaScript from a PDF to an external editor: go into the `Preferences` Menu, and choose the `JavaScript` option:

[image]

From there, select the **`Use external JavaScript editor`** option, and set it to the Text editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The question does indeed not have much to do primarily with programming, and would better be moved to Superuser.

To answer directly to the question and the comment, you specify whether Acrobat's own or an external editor is used in the Javascript tab of the Preferences. There you also specify the application to act as external editor.